# Python unittest when use input is inside a loop

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have the following:

```
def func():
    s = 1
    i = -1
    while i != 0:
        s += i
        i = int(input())
    return s

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = func()
    print(str(result))
```

You will see that there is a single call to the function, but the function contains a loop that iterates until the use enters a value of 0.

How do I test this function with unittest library?

Comment: A good point to start https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/12/09/improve-your-python-understanding-unit-testing/ and https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming your code is inside a module called `mymodule.py`. Therefore, you could create a test file name `test_mymodule.py` to implement your tests. What you want to do is to use the [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) module to have access to the [patch()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) function in order to decorate the builtin input.

What does that mean is that instead of calling the input function to ask for the user input, you are patching it to return the values defined in `side_effect`. Each call of input will therefore return a value of the list. Notice that you should include 0 as well, otherwise the test will not work.

For each sequence of inputs, you will have to compute manually (or even using your program) to provide the final result for the method [assertEqual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual).

```
import unittest                                                                                                                                                                               
import unittest.mock                                                                                                                                                                          

from mymodule import func                                                                                                                                                                     

class TestModule(unittest.TestCase):                                                                                                                                                          

    @unittest.mock.patch('builtins.input', side_effect=[1, 2, 3, 0])                                                                                                                          
    def test_func_list1(self, mock):                                                                                                                                                          
        self.assertEqual(func(), 6)                                                                                                                                                           

    @unittest.mock.patch('builtins.input', side_effect=[0])                                                                                                                                   
    def test_func_list2(self, mock):                                                                                                                                                          
        self.assertEqual(func(), 0)
```

Each test method should be prefixed with a `test_` in its name. The default pattern when using `python -m unittest` from the CLI looks for `test*.py` in the current directory (it is the same as running [TestLoader.discover()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.discover). You can probably change this if you want, but you will have to take a look at the [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) documentation for more details.